# Git export files as zip/tar since specified commit till today

Tags: git, bash

So I want to export all files starting from specific commit id till today (which may include subsequent commits), so I am doing this:

`git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT $commitId | xargs tar -rf output.tar`

However, it seems this outputs file only that were modified in specified commit id (`$commitId`).

What I am looking for though is that it should export all files starting from specified commit id till today (including any further commits that might have happened during the course of the time).

Comment: Could you specify in more detail what you want? Do you want an archive (1) of *all files* in their *current version*, or (2) of *all files* in *all versions* since the specific commit, or (3) the *current version* of the files that have been *changed* since the specific commit (which may not be all files), or (4) *all versions* of the files that have been *changed* since the specific commit (which may not be all files)?

Comment: You may want to use [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) or [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the [Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree):

> git diff-tree - Compares the content and mode of blobs found via two
>   tree objects

...

> If there is only one  given, the commit is compared with its parents (see --stdin below).

In your case you are only giving one `<tree-ish>` so it compares with `$commitId`'s parent. Instead you should provide two `<tree-ish>`es for the comparison to be made between.

Assuming the commits are on the master branch and the master branch is fully up-to-date; then the following command should give what you want:

```
git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT ${commitId}~1 master | xargs tar -rf output.tar
```

The `~1` after `${commitId}` is so make the comparison relative to `${commitId}`'s parent, otherwise the changes in `${commitId}` would not be counted.

Answer (score 5):

```
git diff -z --name-only --diff-filter ACMRT ${commitId}~ HEAD | xargs -0 tar -rf output.tar
```

1. [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) is sufficient; you don't need to use `git diff-tree` to find the list of changed filenames in a commit range.
2. the `-z` option in `git diff` and `-0` in `xargs` makes sure to use `NUL` output field terminators, otherwise any paths/filenames with spaces will cause your command to break.
3. `${commitId}~ HEAD` lists changes between the parent commit of `${commitId}` (so the changes in that commit are included), and the most recent commit (`HEAD`).

Comment: This is your solution.  I'd use ${commitId}~1 instead, because I find it clearer, but it's the same thing.

The nice thing about this solution, too, is that if any files were modified and then modified back (edits undone in a subsequent commit), they will be omitted from the final tar! :-)